# How to print variable values in comment blocks in Julia?

Tags: latex, julia, comments, weave

I'd like to print the value of a variable in comments so I can profit of the LaTeX support in comments and produce nice outputs. Is that even possible?

This is what I tried so far but it only prints the variable's name instead of its value.

```
    my_var = 5
    println("Value of my_var " * my_var)
        
    #'Value of my_var is $(my_var)
```

Also, I use Weave to transform my `.jl` source file into `.html` output file.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to execute Julia code in comment blocks. That's sort the point of comment blocks!

What you can do is to *print the comment block itself*, something like:

```
my_var = 5
println("# The value of my var is: ", my_var)
```

Comment: Right, yeah, but they interpreted in some way since the comments block support LaTeX. Anyway, thanks for your answer but sadly, it doesn't work. It gets interpreted as an output and not text. As excepted :( !

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
my_var = 5
println("Value of my_var $my_var")
```

to show the value of the variable.

In the comment it has not sense, because it is suppose to be comment to reader and they are completely ignored (in any language). However, maybe you can generate the comments as output of your program.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve to get a more precise answer, but I can comment on what you have tried so far.

1. Comments are not meant to interpret code in any language. You need to output your data by some other method. The easiest way is to print information to the screen as you tried with `println`, but you could also print to a file or to another program depending on your goal. You can look up information on Input/Output (I/O) for more information on that. [Link](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/networking-and-streams/)
2. The `println` command you tried did not work because you tried to concatenate (`*`) a string with an integer. You need to convert `my_var` to a string first either with the `string` command or with string expansion (`$`).

```
my_var=5
println("Value of my_var is " * string(my_var))
println("Value of my_var is $my_var")
```

3. If the LaTeX support you need is just Unicode symbols, then that is supported natively by Julia. You can type \alpha in the Julia command line (REPL) or a supported text editor, and it will be converted to the Greek letter itself.
4. For more complete LaTeX support, there is a package you can load into Julia called [LaTexStrings](https://github.com/stevengj/LaTeXStrings.jl) which creates a new LaTeXString class. Putting `L` in front of any string will convert it to a LaTeXSting. Then these LaTeXStrings can be passed through I/O to somewhere which will interpret them. Package installation is covered [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/code-loading/).

Hopefully one of these methods will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Sadly, none of the above worked. But I was able to solve my issue myself ;) !

Answer (score 0):

Turns I simply had to had a 'j' to let markdown know he has to interpret Julia code !

```
my_var = 5
println("Value of my_var " * my_var)

#'Value of my_var is `j my_var`
```

https://github.com/JunoLab/Weave.jl/blob/master/doc/src/usage.md